# Python loop is escaping a value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python. I am using python 2.7.3 and I have written a small function to check if the given number is prime or not.

The code is as follows -

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("1 is neither Prime nor Composite.")
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print("{} equals {} x {}".format(n, x, n // x))
            return False
        else:
            print("{} is a prime number".format(n))
            return True


for n in range(1, 5):
    isprime(n)
```

And the output is -

```
1 is neither Prime nor Composite.
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 x 2
```

Why is it escaping 2. I tried debugging as well but its simple bypassing 2.
Thanks.

Comment: That is not the output I get - for one thing, `5` isn't included in `range(1, 5)`. Please review your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the case where `n == 2`:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1: # nope
        ...
    for x in range(2, n): # here we go
```

So what actually happens?

```
>>> range(2, 2)
[]
```

Nothing; you are iterating over an empty `range`.

Also, you have a logic error - you `return True` if the first value in `range(2, n)` (i.e. `2`) isn't an integer divisor of `n` - you claim than *any odd number* is prime:

```
>>> isprime(9)
9 is a prime number
True # what?!
```

If you dedent the last three lines by one level, it fixes both issues:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print("1 is neither Prime nor Composite.")
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print("{} equals {} x {}".format(n, x, n // x))
            return False
    else:
        print("{} is a prime number".format(n))
        return True
```

*(alternatively, leave out the `else` and dedent the last two lines a further level)*. This gives me:

```
>>> isprime(9)
9 equals 3 x 3
False
>>> isprime(2)
2 is a prime number
True
```

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash remember that whitespace is important in Python!

Comment: coming from javascript background, i completely overlooked it.

Comment: How isprime(9) would to return True in the original logic?

Comment: @user2963623 because `9 % 2 != 0`, which takes you straight into the `else` case

Comment: Sorry! I just realized!

Answer (score 1):

If `n` is `2`, then on the line `for x in range(2, n):` the `range(2, 2)` will return an empty list.